# How to list contents of .zip file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have well over 1000 .zip files that I need to go through looking for .pst files. These .zip files are used by a component of VMware Horizon and unzipping them first is not an option because of this.

I've tried using dir and even dir -force, but these do not dive into the contents of the zip file automatically.

Is there a built-in method in powershell or Windows command prompt that can print the contents of a .zip file without requiring me to decompress the folder first?

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ZipFile class from the .Net framework. To list the entries in an archive file, you may use it like this in Powershell:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')

foreach($sourceFile in (Get-ChildItem -filter '*.zip'))
{
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($sourceFile.FullName).Entries.FullName |
        %{ "$sourcefile`:$_" }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have the PowerShell Community Extensions, you can use its `Read-Archive` cmdlet.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pscx